# How can i skip some divs and classes with Jsoup?

Tags: android, parsing, jsoup

It's me again with my jsoup problem. I'd rather tired this "cooking" but i must finish it.
Can you explain me, how can i skip some divs?

```
<div class="node">

    <div class="content"> 
<p>Черепашка очень ласковая, активная, живая девочка! У неё красивый тигровый окрас и весёлый нрав. Не все собаки сразу подходят к новому человеку, Черепашка же наоборот готова обнять первого встречного, чтобы только обратили на неё внимание, погладили, приласкали. Девочка очень нуждается в человеке, ей не хватает общения в приюте! Она прекрасно ходит на поводке! Готова к весёлым играм и крепким объятиям! Черепашка ждёт добрых и ответственных хозяев!!! </p>
<p>Примерный год рождения 2010, рост около 50 см в холке, привита, чипирована, стерилизована.<br />
чип (643) 110000008982</p>
<p>8-926-683-73-78 Елена<br />
8-909-906-12-55 Александр (Aleksandr) </p>
<p>Очень ласковая контактная собака, постоянно прыгает обниматься! У неё тигровый окрас, может поэтому никак хорошие фото не выходят?!</p>
<p>Видео<br />
<iframe width="420" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/LxZyHaQXmmQ" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe><br />
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/vTuCF-uFcFw" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></p>
 <div class="field field-type-text field-field-english">
    <div class="field-items">
            <div class="field-item odd">
                     <p><span style="font-weight:bold"><span style="font-size:25px">Cherepashka C 72</span></span>....................<span style="font-weight:bold"><span style="font-size:15px">Sector C</span></span></p>
<p>Cherepashka is a very sweet and sociable girl. She jumps up to give you hugs. The color of her coat resembles the one of a tabby cat, maybe because of that we can't take good photos of her?!
</p>
         </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

I have this code (Yea, its on russian). I dont want to parse divs with english words (and classes "field field-type-text field-field-english")

I try to parseit like this:

```
Elements histories = doc.select(".node .content").not(".field");
```

but it doesn't work. I need to understand Jsoup logic first. Thanks!

UPD: I would like to beat the webmaster who made this website. There is sites link http://vao-priut.org/image/cherepashka-metis-gollandskoi-ovcharki-s-72

Comment: I think, that i solved that problem

Comment: If you solved your problem, you could answer your own question, so far everyone can benefit.